# Paris CDG Arrival

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, paris, cdg

My flight will be landing at 7PM (Paris time) at CDG. So I think I would probably be reaching my hotel around 10:30 PM. Can anyone tell me how long does it take in Immigration Control? I will also be coming to Airport Terminal 2C. Can anyone please tell me how do I take the RER b train to Central Paris from that terminal?

Comment: Which airport? RER B runs both to CDG (direct) and to ORY (via Antony).

Comment: I will be coming to CDG. Do I have to switch terminals to take the RER B? Or its there in all terminals?

Comment: RER B has two stops at CDG: CDG 1, and CDG 2/TGV. The RER stations are directly beneath the terminals.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Map over CDG]

As you can see [Terminal 2C](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/terminals-map) is directly connected to the RER Station. "Just follow the signs". It's a bit tricky to find the station first time and even trickier to get the right ticket from the machines, but there is staff there that can help you. Expect 13 € for the train ticket. Get some one-time tickets for the metro while you're at it - you'll need them.

[image: The RER Platforms at CDG]

The time at immigrations could be anything from 10 seconds to 2 hours. I haven't passed it there.

There are multiple stores there that will sell you a SIM Card - don't get scammed by them, some are super expensive.

---

I suggest using Google Maps for finding directions in Paris, it works really well with RER, metro and everything. Also, the kickscooters are very fun and the fastest way to get anywhere - just drive safe.

Answer (score 5):

How long it takes at immigration varies a lot depending on your citizenship, your type of visa, whether you have status (elite frequent flyers and premium passengers often have access to fast track, depending on the airline), how busy it is, and so on. It is quite difficult to predict (unless you are an EU national with a e-passport and fast track, in which case it's usually a few minutes). I would probably budget up to 2 hours, though it may be much faster.

Charles de Gaulle has 2 RER stations, one of which is in the train station which sits right between terminals A, B, C and D on one side and terminals E and F on the other.

From Terminal 2C, once you have gone through passport control, reclaimed your bags, and gone through customs, turn right, and walk 300 meters, and there you are, the train station!

Take the first escalators on your left down two levels (follow the signs for "trains to Paris" / RER B), on your right you will find ticket windows and ticket machines. Make sure you are using the windows/machines for local trains and not for long distance. Buy a ticket, go through the ticket gates, and go down one more level to the platform (again, follow signs for "trains to Paris" / RER B).

All RER B trains go to Paris (and then on to various destinations south of Paris), though some are non-stop until Gare du Nord, while others will stop in stations along the way, it's usually better to take the non-stop (you'll have more space for luggage).

Comment: Could you explain how you purchase tickets? I found it very confusing.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder At a window or at a machine? A regular one-way ticket to Paris? At a window it should be as easy as "X tickets to Paris please" and at a machine it's probably the first option on the screen.

Comment: I'm wondering... Maybe you tried to use the long-distance ticket machines instead of those for regional trains?

Comment: I used [the machines right above the platform](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT9G8XcU8Cg4NV3xT6l88sRgjtweu0yR94K5tCUvnPOVuMvZjfgCg). I refused to set it to English which made it a bit harder (only used Google translate for the numbers at McDonalds, practising my french). I tried to find some suitable multi day ticket, maybe even a return ticket to the airport etc.

Comment: Fast track on arrival immigration? Also, how does the type of visa figure into it? It's mostly French/EU/EEA vs. other passports. Even if you don't need a visa, you will end up in line with everybody else.

Answer (score 4):

[This webpage](https://parisbytrain.com/charles-de-gaulle-airport-cdg-to-paris-by-train/) contains the following current details about taking the RER B from CDG to central Paris:

***CDG to Paris Train Overview***

*Line => RER B (Blue) RER B Train*

*Direction => Paris (Robinson, Antony, St-Rémy-lès-Chevreuse)*

*Arrival Stations => Gare du Nord, Châtelet les Halles, St Michel/Nôtre Dame, Luxembourg, Port Royal, Denfert-Rochereau, Cité Universitaire*

*Ticket => “Billet Ile-de-France” Aéroport CDG – Paris (Zone 5 -> Zone 1)*

*Cost => 10.30€ (adult fare) / 7€ (children 4 – 9) / free (children under 4) Prices as of June 1, 2019*

*Passes Accepted => Paris Visite, Navigo Pass, Navigo Day Pass, Ticket Mobilis*

*First Train / Last RER B Train CDG to Paris => 04:56 / 23:50*

Comment: Could you explain how to get to the station from Terminal 2C?

Comment: I follow the signs. Works every time.